# Why cannot C type-generic expressions be compatible with C++?

Tags: c++, c, c11

I seem to recall hearing vague comments from a few reliable sources (i.e. committee members speaking in non-official channels) that C type-generic expressions will not be added to C++ because they cannot be.

As far as I can tell, type-generic expressions are very limited compared to C++ templates and overloading, but there is no potential for interaction that would need to be defined as a special case.

A type-generic expression consists of a controlling expression, and a series of "associations" between types and subexpressions. A subexpression is chosen based on the static type of the controlling expression and the types listed for the subexpressions, and it is substituted in place of the TGE. Matching is based on the C concept of type compatibility, which as far as I can tell is equivalent to C++ identity of types with `extern` linkage under the one-definition rule (ODR).

It would be nice if a derived class controlling expression would select a base class association in C++, but since C doesn't have inheritance, such nicety isn't needed for cross-compatibility. Is this considered to be a stumbling block anyway?

**Edit:** As for more specific details, C11 already provides for preserving the value category (lvalue-ness) of the chosen subexpression, and seems to require that the TGE is a constant expression (of whatever category) as long as all its operands are, including the controlling expression. This is probably a C language defect. In any case, C++14 defines constant expressions in terms of what may be potentially evaluated, and the TGE spec already says that non-chosen subexpressions are unevaluated.

The point is that the TGE principle of operation seems simple enough to be transplanted without ever causing trouble later.

As for *why* C++ TGE's would be useful, aside from maximizing the intersection of C and C++, they could be used to essentially implement `static_if`, sans the highly controversial conditional declaration feature. I'm not a proponent of `static_if`, but "there is that."

```
template< typename t >
void f( t q ) {
    auto is_big = _Generic( std::integral_constant< bool, sizeof q >= 4 >(),
        std::true_type: std::string( "whatta whopper" ),
        std::false_type: "no big deal"
    );
    auto message = _Generic( t, double: "double", int: 42, default: t );
    std::cout << message << " " << is_big << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Maybe the thing in charge of resolving the generic has to come before the thing that figures out how classes work. So you wouldn't be able to genericize classes, and thus you would have a feature that only works on SOME types.

Comment: @leewangzhong Well, it would work the same as in C. It would work on all types, just not with insight into inheritance.

Comment: I mean, maybe C++ types aren't recognized by the time the generics are resolved.

Comment: @leewangzhong: C++ would have to specify how `_Generic` works, and C++ certainly would specify that it's resolved after C++ types are recognized. (That's fairly early anyway, because parsing needs it. See "most vexing parse" for more details.)

Comment: Can you give us the sources saying it's impossible? Context might help.

Comment: "Cannot be" is maybe too strong. But if you are realistic, C++ has not much need for them, since most of the intended use of TG can be done with other c++ constructs. And then these are mainly not API relevant, so a coding feature (in contrast to an interface feature). Both languages are already incompatible on that level, anyhow. So there is not much too gain.

Comment: Is there *any* situation in C++, where you would want to use this instead of overloads or templates? Even for multilanguage header files, #ifdef works and compatible macro can be produced for both.

Comment: @hyde The use case I can think of is migration of otherwise unadventurous C code to C++. But yeah, as long as the use case is in fact generic programming, it's easy enough to substitute a template by `#ifdef`. So really I'm just curious whether there is any technical hurdle.

Comment: @leewangzhong I don't have a link on hand, and might as well not point fingers… but I just recall offhand remarks with little depth. Call it a strawman for now.

Comment: Can't you `extern "C"` for code migration?

Answer (score 2):

"Cannot be" is perhaps too strong. "Uncertain whether it's possible" is more likely.

If this feature were to be added to C++, it should be fully specified including all interactions with existing C++ features, many of which were not designed with `_Generic` in mind. E.g. `typeid` doesn't exist in C, but should work in C++. Can you use a `_Generic` expression as a `constexpr`? As a template parameter? Is it an `lvalue` ? Can you take its address and assign that to a function pointer, and get overload resolution? Can you do template argument deduction? Can you use it with `auto`? Etc.

Another complication is that the primary usecase for `_Generic` is for macro's, which don't play nice with C++ namespaces. The `acos` example from `tgmath` is a clear example. C++ already banned C's standard macro's and required them to be functions, but that won't work with `tgmath.h`.

Comment: These sound more like tick marks that need to be checked for no interaction. The idea is that one subexpression is selected and substituted for the entire expression. As such there seems to be no room for interaction with any of the things you've mentioned. As for the `tgmath` macros, they're already superceded by overload sets since C++98.